# Styled components center vertically

Tags: html, css, styled-components, styling

I am having trouble "col 1 text" to center vertically. Here is a example of what I have:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <ColOneContainer>
          col 1 text
        </ColOneContainer>
        <ColTwoContainer>
          <div>text that might run one line or two</div>
          <div>text that might run one line or two</div>
        </ColTwoContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

const ColOneContainer = styled.div`
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
`

const ColTwoContainer = styled.div`
  margin-left: 25%;
`;

const ColTwoContainer = styled.div`
  margin-left: 25%;
`;
```

which gives an output like this:
[image]

I have multiple rows of "MyComponent" so I cannot use `position: absolute;`
Can anyone help me center the "col 1 text" vertically to make it look like this:
[image]

Comment: Just to note, the text in the "ColTwoContainer" might be long, so I cannot use "padding-top: 10rem"

Answer (score 0):

you can try table-cell to achieve this...

```
 const ColOneContainer = styled.div`
      float: left;
      width: 25%
      display: table-cell; 
      vertical-align: middle;
   '
 ;
```

have a look at http://howtocenterincss.com/ also

Comment: This did not solve the issue. But thanks for the howtocenterincss site, very cool site